# Выдает ошибку 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x072A93E2

Tags: c++

Выдает ошибку 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x072A93E2 при компиляции в конструкторе. Пробовала разные методы, но не помогает. Как исправить?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Array {
private:
    string arr[5];
    int w[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
public:
    Array(string arr[]) {
        this->arr[5] = arr[5];
    }
    void enter() {
        cout << "Enter the line: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            cin >> arr[i];
        }
    }

    void sort() {
        string s1, s2;
        for (int j = 5; j > 0; j--) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                    s1 = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                    arr[i + 1] = s1;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "Your array: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            cout << arr[i] << "\t" << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
    }

    void words() {
        string ser;
        cout << "The array of amounts of words in every line: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            ser = arr[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < ser.length(); j++)
            {
                if (isspace(ser[j]) && !isspace(ser[j + 1])) w[i]++;
            }
            w[i]++;
            cout << w[i] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
    ~Array() {};
};

void main()
{
    string arr[5];
    Array a(arr);
    a.enter();
    a.sort();
    a.words();
}
```

Comment: не писать  arr[5]

Comment: а как тогда? если совсем не писать скобочек (или оставить их пустыми), то уже другая ошибка:(

Comment: ваш массив  состоит из 5 пустых строк, вы пытаетесь инициалировать шестую(arr[5] ), а шестой у вас нет. К тому же  неизвестно каким массивом окажется аргумент конструктора. Плюс ко всему, старайтесь писать код со смыслом... К тому же  у вас еще другие ошибки

Comment: Нет способа скопировать весь массив разом. Используйте цикл (или `std::copy`, который внутри тоже использует цикл). Еще: *"Выдает ошибку ... при компиляции"* Не-а, при выполнении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы выходите за пределы массива. Исправил так :

```
for (int j = 5; j > 0; j--) {
   for (int i = 0; i < /*5*/4; i++) {
```

Ещё убрал лишний код:

```
Array(/*string arr[]*/) {
        //this->arr[5] = arr[5];
    }
```

...

```
int/*void*/ main()
{
    //string arr[5];
    Array a/*(arr)*/;
```